# How to jump into specific page in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

An input box to enter a specific page number. On keyup, the datatable has to be on the typed page number with corresponding data

Tried `page()` api

```
var table = $('#dataList').DataTable({});
table.page(2).draw( 'page' );
```

But not working. is there any solution to do the same.

Comment: Look at the console, Is there any error occurred prior to this line.. because code looks fine and it's working

Comment: Please see: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Please also see: [mcve] - as all you've given us is "it's not working", it could be any thing, eg jquery not included, datatables not initialised, keyup on the wrong element, etc etc - so any possible solution will be just a *guess*.   Please include enough code/html/css to be able to *reproduce* the issue.  See also the [SO wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) for datatables which provides some starter code for a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
   var pageNo =6
   table.page(pageNo-1).draw('page');
} );
```

its working for me check this [demo](http://live.datatables.net/femozipe/1/edit)